# ListCollectionView with LiveSorting and CustomSort with inherit

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a ListCollectionView (used by a wpf TreeView) with a custom sort and the live sorting enable.
Every things works fine, until I wanted to do some inheritance on custom sort class.

This is the working customSort class

```
public class NaturalTreeSorter : IComparer
{
    private static readonly Regex m_IntRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is ITree treeX && y is ITree treeY)
        {
            return Compare(treeX.Name, treeY.Name);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare 2 string using natural (based on http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting )
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        object convert(string str)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(str, out int integer))
                return integer;
            else
                return str;
        }
        var xArray = m_IntRegex.Split(x).Select(convert);
        var yArray = m_IntRegex.Split(y).Select(convert);
        return Compare(xArray, yArray);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two sequences of T. (based on http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting )
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">First sequence.</param>
    /// <param name="y">Second sequence.</param>
    protected int Compare<T>(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> leftIt = x.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<T> rightIt = y.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                bool left = leftIt.MoveNext();
                bool right = rightIt.MoveNext();

                if (!(left || right)) return 0;

                if (!left) return -1;
                if (!right) return 1;

                int itemResult = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(leftIt.Current, rightIt.Current);
                if (itemResult != 0) return itemResult;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I replace by (move everything except Compare(object x, object y)):

```
public class NaturalTreeSorter : NaturalStringSorter, IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is ITree treeX && y is ITree treeY)
        {
            return Compare(treeX.Name, treeY.Name);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

public class NaturalStringSorter : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly Regex m_IntRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare 2 string using natural (based on http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting )
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        object convert(string str)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(str, out int integer))
                return integer;
            else
                return str;
        }
        var xArray = m_IntRegex.Split(x).Select(convert);
        var yArray = m_IntRegex.Split(y).Select(convert);
        return Compare(xArray, yArray);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two sequences of T. (based on http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting )
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">First sequence.</param>
    /// <param name="y">Second sequence.</param>
    protected int Compare<T>(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> leftIt = x.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<T> rightIt = y.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                bool left = leftIt.MoveNext();
                bool right = rightIt.MoveNext();

                if (!(left || right)) return 0;

                if (!left) return -1;
                if (!right) return 1;

                int itemResult = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(leftIt.Current, rightIt.Current);
                if (itemResult != 0) return itemResult;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this new code, the ListCollectionView is not sorted when the property used in LiveSortingProperties changed.

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there may be collision of `Compare` methods.

try composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class NaturalTreeSorter : IComparer
{
    private NaturalStringSorter sorter = new NaturalStringSorter();

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is ITree treeX && y is ITree treeY)
        {
            return sorter.Compare(treeX.Name, treeY.Name);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```